# Find the index of reflection of a substring of a palindrome

Tags: code-golf, string, palindrome

**Problem Statement**:
You will receive a substring of a palindromic string. You must return the index of the substring which marks the point of reflection of the original string. You are only provided the substring, which is not necessarily a palindrome because it is not necessarily centered about the middle of the original palindromic string.

**Input**: Substring of length `2n + 1,  1 <= n <= 1000`, which encompasses the center of reflection of some larger palindromic string.

**Output**: Return the index of the substring which marks the point of reflection. May be 0-indexed or 1-indexed.

**Test cases** (character at desired index is bold to show the desired output more clearly):

*Input*

1. manaplana**c**analpan
2. car**o**racati
3. wlatem**y**meta
4. na**s**anita

*Output*

1. 9 (the full string was “a man a plan a canal panama”, with spaces removed)
2. 4 (the full string was “was it a car or a cat i saw”, with spaces removed)
3. 6 (the full string was “mr owl are my metal worm”, with spaces removed)
4. 2 (the full string was “oozy rat in a sanitary zoo”, with spaces removed)

**Winning Criterion**: This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) Shortest code in bytes wins.

**Assumption**: Assume there is just a single candidate palindrome

**Restriction**:`0` and `2n` (last index) are invalid output.

Comment: Shortest code in bytes.

Comment: May we assume there is a unique candidate for the center of the palindrome in the substring we are given? Eg. consider being given `abab` as a substring.

Comment: Yes, assume there is just a sole candidate.

Comment: I think `1` is a valid output for `acaroracati`, no?

Comment: Can we accept a list of letters instead of a string, please?

Comment: "in girum imus nocte et consumimur igni" Can you add a test case of this palindrome?

Comment: Suggested test case: `abcdcba`, or any other example where the substring is a palindrome.

Comment: As pointed out by @Sisyphus, the 2nd test case does not follow the assumption that there's a sole candidate. Besides, the first and the last character in any input string could be considered 1-character palindromic substrings as well. I guess we're actually looking for the index that maximizes the size of the palindrome, but this is currently not explicitly stated.

Comment: How about this: `abcddcba`. This is why I used the famous `in girum imus nocte et consumimur igni`

Comment: @J42161217 This one is not of size `2n + 1`, though.

Comment: @Arnauld I meant this as the main string. A substring would be `bcddbca`. Or `usnocteetconsumimurigni` of the latin double palindrome. The thing here is that a center character doesn't exist. Also, "You are only provided the substring" and I think that OP should clarify if the hole string is a valid input

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear until the issues are resolved that were pointed out with centers other than the claimed sole candidate.

Comment: @Arnauld Don't you mean *minimize* the size of the candidate palindrome?

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter My understanding is that we have to find `acar[o]raca` in `acaroracati` rather than just `a[c]a`.

Comment: @Arnauld I'm not sure I understand you. Maybe you have what is a substring mixed up?  We should find `acar[o]raca`, I agree but as opposed to `acarorac[a]caroraca` or `acarora[c]aroraca`.  Of these the one we want is the shortest.  Here our input is the substring of the palindrome rather than the palindrome being a substring of our string.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Hmm, I don’t think so. Would this make it much easier for you?

Comment: I fixed the second test case such that it only has one solution. Assume there is only one solution please (excluding indices 0 and 2n)

Comment: @RyanRudes It's up to you, but some languages very succinctly handle strings, and some don't.  My usual language is R, in which string operations are usually quite verbose.  So if the 'core' of the challenge isn't really affected, it can often make it more attractive for some languages (or some approaches) by allowing more flexible input.  In this case I think the first thing I'd want to do would be split-up the string, and this would use-up bytes for a rather trivial input-processing operation.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Alright then, I suppose it’s fine.

Comment: @RyanRudes, As Arnauld said, I believe what you want is "maximum possible palindromic substring," which should make the problem well-defined.  I simply assumed that in my answer since it made sense and removed ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>26</sup> 25 bytes

```
[:(-:@i.>./)[:(*/*#)/.=/~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o600dK0cMvXs9PQ1gWwtfS1lTX09W/26/5pcXFypyRn5CmkK6rmJeYkFOUAiGYhzChLz1BX8nPQULOEKgBJF@UVAsiQTImUClyrPSSxJza3MTS1JhEiZwaXyEosT8zJh4kb/AQ)

### how

`=/~` creates a function table comparing all possible pairs of characters.  Taking `'nasanita'` as an example:

```
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Notice the `/`-direction diagonals.  If one of those is all ones, it corresponds to an embedded palindrome.

J has an adverb `/.` which lets us to apply a verb to each diagonal.

We choose the verb `(*/*#)` -- the sum multiplied by the length.  Thus it will be the length of the diagonal if it's all ones, and 0 otherwise:

```
1 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

`i.>./` Find the index of the max element within that list.  In this case the index of 5 is 4.

`-:@` And divide it by 2.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was returning 0. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>47</s> 40 bytes

```perl6
{m:ex/.+)>.<{$/.flip}>/.max(*.chars).to}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYuxCgMhEAV7v8IihFwCa5ciJPcvj0OJsKuyCjk57tuNxQzTTPHKzyHdXoP9jENefnf0WFZ6HxdHgWM5V0eC/Xan7QutC7V8jopuaS4hq@WYfB2ChMJT24QLkpmlWadbND9G89LFN5iEihQb/g)

Match all palindromes in the string, find the maximum length one, and output its center index.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes

```
f=lambda s,n=1:n*(s[n+1:2*n+1]==s[n-1:n-len(s)<<1:-1])or f(s,n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7NCsMgDIDP7VPkUtT@HOxR6pMUD9naMkFTqcIo7N27dAzMl3yBJKazvHYar2uzAeNjQcg9WW2olXmmTpuxZTpr2QZuD2ElmdU0aTNop/YDNskTnVbXxpLBE8wiImEKjCdHSEiiB8Fy7Aez@FvfAcsaz7gWvJUwI3munakrD/beq@oqHZ6KFE020Cwgm/z5PSWgAT4Mvoc8G@/u9Cd/2ilVX18)

---

Consider the string `abcdefg`. Here's what it looks like checking for palindromes around each character:

```
abcdefg
a c
ab de
abc efg
  cd fg
    e g
```

We see for the right string, the index goes from `n+1` to `2*n+1`. The left string is trickier, but looking in reverse (starting from the end of the string) we start at `n-1` and move to `2*(n-len(s))` (this is a negative number that indexes from the back of the string). Since we can assume there is only one viable palindrome candidate, we can terminate early if we find one.

---

#### Python 3.8, 72 bytes

```
f=lambda s,t='':(max(k:=s[1:],t).find(min(k,t))==0)*len(t)or f(k,s[0]+t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BasQwDEXXk1NoE2x1TJnSTTH4JCELtUmoGVsxlqAd6N1TpRSk9/W0EGoP/dz59a3149hSofq@EEjQ5Fz0lb79PSaZXuIcFJ@3zIuvmf3dDFO64VNZ2SvuHTZbynSbr4rHZi6QGSZXiakVw4d1acQugDPpezdqPvWrkK71UVelU5mEONs8x@GSIdlpweHSemb1bpQI4wJ@lJ@/QgcjeAmQA8gU83zGP6/2N@Jw/AI)

This approach seemed promising but was just longer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 53 bytes

```
Lv$`((.)+).(?<-2>\2)+(?(2)(?!))
$.1;$.($`$1
N`
L`\d+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcbBCgIhEIDh@7xFMMEMsoJeizx2WXqCPTiUB0GnxaTYpzcP/8ffUs8qbpzpHsf6xUhk2bClcF38bfNsKJBnCidmQOsuaAkjOnhEWOP2MjhGFZW9TJ6zsovCvPZu057hV6SnetTUBVQ@ornLHw) Link includes test cases. 0-indexed. Explanation:

```
((.)+).(?<-2>\2)+(?(2)(?!))
```

Match and separately capture a number of characters in `\2`, then match the centre character, then match and pop each character from `\2`, ensuring that all matched characters get popped. This therefore ensures that the whole match is a palindrome.

```
Lv$`
$.1;$.($`$1
```

Consider all overlapping matches and output the length of the palindromic prefix and position of the centre (which is the position of the match plus the length of the palindromic prefix).

```
N`
```

Sort in order of length.

```
L`\d+$
```

Take the position of the last (i.e. longest) match.